# UTF-8 selenium error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, utf-8, webdriver

I want to get all correios agency info in Brasil. I'm trying to webscrape the daa by selenium, but im having issues due to utf-8, how can i set everything to utf-8?
Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time     

chrome_path = r"D:\Users\gbenites\Desktop\Inovação\arquivos py\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/agencias/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'municipioAgencia')))
driver.maximize_window()


time.sleep(3) #this time allows the page load all the elements
estadoList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('estadoAgencia'))
for index in range(1,len(estadoList.options)):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('estadoAgencia'))
    print("selecting Estado",select.options[index].text)
    select.select_by_index(index)
    time.sleep(2)
    municípioList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
    for index_b in range(1,len(municípioList.options)):
        select_b = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
        print("...selecting Municipio",select_b.options[index_b].text)
        select_b.select_by_index(index_b)
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Here's the error:

```
selecting Estado ACRE
...selecting Municipio ACRELANDIA               
...selecting Municipio ASSIS BRASIL             
...selecting Municipio BRASILEIA                
...selecting Municipio BUJARI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPIXABA                 
...selecting Municipio CRUZEIRO DO SUL          
...selecting Municipio EPITACIOLANDIA           
...selecting Municipio FEIJO                    
...selecting Municipio JORDAO                   
...selecting Municipio MANCIO LIMA              
...selecting Municipio MANOEL URBANO            
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL THAUMATURGO     
...selecting Municipio PLACIDO DE CASTRO        
...selecting Municipio PORTO ACRE               
...selecting Municipio PORTO WALTER             
...selecting Municipio RIO BRANCO               
...selecting Municipio RODRIGUES ALVES          
...selecting Municipio SANTA ROSA DO PURUS      
...selecting Municipio SENA MADUREIRA           
...selecting Municipio SENADOR GUIOMARD         
...selecting Municipio TARAUACA                 
...selecting Municipio XAPURI                   
selecting Estado ALAGOAS
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE
```

When a State with utf-8 error shows, it starts to repeat the counties, how can i put the State info in utf-8?

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-case you are facing an error while interpreting **utf-8** characters you can add a line at the begining of your *Python* file as:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
```

---

### Update

With a simple text change of **municípioList** to **municipioList** within the lines:

```
municipioList = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('municipioAgencia'))
```

and

```
for index_b in range(1,len(municipioList.options)):
```

I haven't faced the error line as:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

Console Output:

```
selecting Estado ACRE
...selecting Municipio ACRELANDIA               
...selecting Municipio ASSIS BRASIL             
...selecting Municipio BRASILEIA                
...selecting Municipio BUJARI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPIXABA                 
...selecting Municipio CRUZEIRO DO SUL          
...selecting Municipio EPITACIOLANDIA           
...selecting Municipio FEIJO                    
...selecting Municipio JORDAO                   
...selecting Municipio MANCIO LIMA              
...selecting Municipio MANOEL URBANO            
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL THAUMATURGO     
...selecting Municipio PLACIDO DE CASTRO        
...selecting Municipio PORTO ACRE               
...selecting Municipio PORTO WALTER             
...selecting Municipio RIO BRANCO               
...selecting Municipio RODRIGUES ALVES          
...selecting Municipio SANTA ROSA DO PURUS      
...selecting Municipio SENA MADUREIRA           
...selecting Municipio SENADOR GUIOMARD         
...selecting Municipio TARAUACA                 
...selecting Municipio XAPURI                   
selecting Estado ALAGOAS
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
selecting Estado AMAPÁ
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
selecting Estado AMAZONAS
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
selecting Estado BAHIA
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
selecting Estado CEARÁ
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio CANAPI                   
...selecting Municipio CAPELA                   
...selecting Municipio CARNEIROS                
...selecting Municipio CHA PRETA                
...selecting Municipio COITE DO NOIA            
...selecting Municipio COLONIA LEOPOLDINA       
...selecting Municipio COQUEIRO SECO            
...selecting Municipio CORURIPE                 
...selecting Municipio CRAIBAS                  
...selecting Municipio DELMIRO GOUVEIA          
...selecting Municipio DOIS RIACHOS             
...selecting Municipio ESTRELA DE ALAGOAS       
...selecting Municipio FEIRA GRANDE             
...selecting Municipio FELIZ DESERTO            
...selecting Municipio FLEXEIRAS                
...selecting Municipio GIRAU DO PONCIANO        
...selecting Municipio IBATEGUARA               
...selecting Municipio IGACI                    
...selecting Municipio IGREJA NOVA              
...selecting Municipio INHAPI                   
...selecting Municipio JACARE DOS HOMENS        
...selecting Municipio JACUIPE                  
...selecting Municipio JAPARATINGA              
...selecting Municipio JARAMATAIA               
...selecting Municipio JEQUIA DA PRAIA          
...selecting Municipio JOAQUIM GOMES            
...selecting Municipio JUNDIA                   
...selecting Municipio JUNQUEIRO                
...selecting Municipio LAGOA DA CANOA           
...selecting Municipio LIMOEIRO DE ANADIA       
...selecting Municipio MACEIO                   
...selecting Municipio MAJOR ISIDORO            
...selecting Municipio MAR VERMELHO             
...selecting Municipio MARAGOGI                 
...selecting Municipio MARAVILHA                
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL DEODORO         
...selecting Municipio MARIBONDO                
...selecting Municipio MATA GRANDE              
...selecting Municipio MATRIZ DE CAMARAGIBE     
...selecting Municipio MESSIAS                  
...selecting Municipio MINADOR DO NEGRAO        
...selecting Municipio MONTEIROPOLIS            
...selecting Municipio MURICI                   
...selecting Municipio NOVO LINO                
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DAS FLORES   
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO    
...selecting Municipio OLHO D'AGUA GRANDE       
...selecting Municipio OLIVENCA                 
...selecting Municipio OURO BRANCO              
...selecting Municipio PALESTINA                
...selecting Municipio PALMEIRA DOS INDIOS      
...selecting Municipio PAO DE ACUCAR            
...selecting Municipio PARICONHA                
...selecting Municipio PARIPUEIRA               
...selecting Municipio PASSO DE CAMARAGIBE      
...selecting Municipio PAULO JACINTO            
...selecting Municipio PENEDO                   
...selecting Municipio PIACABUCU                
...selecting Municipio PILAR                    
...selecting Municipio PINDOBA                  
...selecting Municipio PIRANHAS                 
...selecting Municipio POCO DAS TRINCHEIRAS     
...selecting Municipio PORTO CALVO              
...selecting Municipio PORTO DE PEDRAS          
...selecting Municipio PORTO REAL DO COLEGIO    
...selecting Municipio QUEBRANGULO              
...selecting Municipio RIO LARGO                
...selecting Municipio ROTEIRO                  
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO IPANEMA       
...selecting Municipio SANTANA DO MUNDAU        
...selecting Municipio SAO BRAS                 
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA LAJE         
...selecting Municipio SAO JOSE DA TAPERA       
...selecting Municipio SAO LUIS DO QUITUNDE     
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS    
...selecting Municipio SAO MIGUEL DOS MILAGRES  
...selecting Municipio SAO SEBASTIAO            
...selecting Municipio SATUBA                   
...selecting Municipio SENADOR RUI PALMEIRA     
...selecting Municipio TANQUE D'ARCA            
...selecting Municipio TAQUARANA                
...selecting Municipio TEOTONIO VILELA          
...selecting Municipio TRAIPU                   
...selecting Municipio UNIAO DOS PALMARES       
...selecting Municipio VICOSA                   
selecting Estado DISTRITO FEDERAL
...selecting Municipio AGUA BRANCA              
...selecting Municipio ANADIA                   
...selecting Municipio ARAPIRACA                
...selecting Municipio ATALAIA                  
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO   
...selecting Municipio BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL      
...selecting Municipio BATALHA                  
...selecting Municipio BELEM                    
...selecting Municipio BELO MONTE               
...selecting Municipio BOCA DA MATA             
...selecting Municipio BRANQUINHA               
...selecting Municipio CACIMBINHAS              
...selecting Municipio CAJUEIRO                 
...selecting Municipio CAMPESTRE                
...selecting Municipio CAMPO ALEGRE             
...selecting Municipio CAMPO GRANDE
```

Comment: The code don't recognize the non utf-8 strings and keep printing the same counties

Comment: Is the error happening in the line `print("...selecting Municipio",select_b.options[index_b].text)`?

Comment: the code don't get a error by itself, it just shows in the output [Decode error - output not utf-8] and after that, the counties start to repeat

Comment: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49582/devtools/browser/40f7eb1e-0e34-4ffd-b1f0-8d79186408fd
selecting Estado ACRE
...selecting Municipio ACRELANDIA
...selecting Municipio ASSIS BRASIL
...selecting Municipio BRASILEIA
...selecting Municipio BUJARI
...selecting Municipio CAPIXABA
...selecting Municipio CRUZEIRO DO SUL
...selecting Municipio EPITACIOLANDIA
...selecting Municipio FEIJO
...selecting Municipio JORDAO
...selecting Municipio MANCIO LIMA
...selecting Municipio MANOEL URBANO
...selecting Municipio MARECHAL THAUMATURGO
the start of the output

Comment: I think that the error show up because the website realize i'm runing a robot and gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, so nothing in the website's going to change. Do you know anything i can do?

Comment: @GustavoMolina Not sure about the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` but seems to be a different issue from the one within this question as `[Decode error - output not utf-8]`. Of-coarse there are certain things we can attempt in-case the website realize you are running a robot but that is out of scope for this question.